# How to sort user input using comparator on 2d arrays

Tags: java, arrays, comparator

I have searched through the internet on how to use this `comparator` in sorting but most of them are only showing examples that are single dimension arrays and the value are not user input. I have never used this `comparator` yet.

I have tried some examples that I have found in this site, but have resulted in errors that I don't know yet since I haven't tried using comparator yet.

`UPDATE: The code is finished but there's an error on the output`

```
import java.util.*;

public class OhBoy{
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    char userchoice;

    String[] org = {"ID","AT","CBT","P"};
    String[] orga = {"ID","Arrival Time","CPU Burst Time","Priority"};

    String[][] infos = new String[5][4];

    //Reminder
    System.out.println("***When setting priority 1 is highest and 5 is lowest***");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    //End user inputs values
    for(int a = 0;a<5;a++){
        for(int b = 0;b<4;b++){
            System.out.print(orga[b]+": ");
            infos[a][b] = sc.next();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


    System.out.println();
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("--Choose sorting method--");
    System.out.println("--------");

    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("1 - Arrival Time");
    System.out.println("2 - CPU Burst Time");
    System.out.println("3 - Priority");

    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Your choice: ");
    userchoice = sc.next().charAt(0);


    for(int c = 0;c<4;c++){
        System.out.print(org + "\t");
    }

    System.out.println();


    if(userchoice == 1){
        Arrays.sort(infos, new SortByArrival());
        print(infos);
    } else {

    }


}

public static void print(String[][] infos){
    for (String[] array : infos){
        for (String s : array){
            System.out.print(s + " ");
        }
    System.out.println();
    } 
}
}



class SortByArrival implements Comparator{
public int compare(final Object infoss1, final Object infoss2){
    final String f1 = ((String[])infoss1)[1];
    final String f2 = ((String[])infoss2)[1];
    return f1.compareTo(f2);
}
}
```

This is the error that pops up when it tries to print the sorted array

`[Ljava.lang.String;@90f6bfd     [Ljava.lang.String;@90f6bfd     [Ljava.lang.String;@90f6bfd     [Ljava.lang.String;@90f6bfd`

Comment: I updated the code since there's a new problem I encountered.

Comment: definition of a static function inside of functionbody is not allowed.

Comment: so how should it be? T-T and btw I have a problem on the Arrays.sort(infos, new SortByArrival())

Comment: Fix at least the {}, the static function must be define on class-level.

Comment: the output is now the problem. Almost everything is fixed except the one that prints the whole output.

Comment: You are trying to print Arrays of Strings, not Strings. That leads to this output.

Comment: so how should I call the arrays of string since it shoud've called it in the first place since when you sort an array all you have to do was call the variable, right?

Comment: I fear you are lacking some fundamental java, even programming language-skills. I think stackoverflow is no place to teach those. This looks like your first attempts in coding, if they are not, and you already did work with another programming language, perhaps look for a book that compares this language with java.

Comment: oh dude, no worries, I finally fixed the entire code, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
public int compare(String[][] infoss, String[][] infoss){
```

The method receive 2 parameters with the same name. Change it to:

```
public int compare(String[][] infoss1, String[][] infoss2){
```